# Is developing a webbased app more efficient with Ext JS/Dojo & et al than with HTML/JQuery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, web-applications, extjs, dojo

The server side is pretty much set up, it's basically
struts 2 / spring security / jpa.

Now I have to decide what to do with the client side (the browser). The client side codebase should be maintainable and should lend itself to automatic regression testing.

So as an example lets say I need a table component having properties such as

- sortable/pageable columns
- reordering of rows and columns (via drag & drop)
- inline editing of table cells
- remembers state when customer re-visits page
- integrates easily with struts 2

As far as I understand things there're 4 alternatives

1. DIY using oldschool HTML + JQuery + Ajax
2. Finding a JQuery plugin that does all this or
3. plumb together different plug-ins (like [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) + additional plug-in for drag & drop)
4. Using a JS toolkit

Should I stick with JQuery? Or should I go for fullblown JS toolkits? I have little experience with JQuery and JS toolkits (I'm not a web developer).

Thank you for helping a serverside programmer cross the messy world of web-ui-programmming ;)

Comment: Right tools for right job. Depending on what you need you could choose anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that Dojo's support for programming-in-the-large is great if you have a large-scale app that will benefit from the build system, class system, widgeting system and integrated widgeting library.  It also of course brings all the standard stuff with it, like cross-browser support and event system.

If you just need some widgets and animations then any library will work.  I'd stick with the one you/your team knows best.  jQuery definitely has the greatest number of people with that skillset.

Answer (score 2):

Our team wasted 6 months trying to give the client what they wanted with JQuery/UI, and we switched to ExtJS 4, and the client is happy after 2 months. This is an app with 50+ models.

JQuery/UI is NOT designed for web applications. It is designed for web SITES. Sure, it has some good plugins, but you'll spend countless hours learning their apis and switching your thought process between them all. JQuery/UI lacks the following:

- a graphical designer (see Sencha Designer 2), ie graphical layout GUI program
- complicated layouts (in ext you can switch a layout of a container to accordion, tabs, wizard, anchors with one setting)
- a grid (ext grid supports paging, sorting, filtering, grouping, summaries, editing out of the box)
- real comboboxes
- a model view controller system
- templating
- good html editor control
- a whole ton of other stuff

do yourself a favour and spend the money on ext, and save yourself countless hours.

regarding the grid you mentioned, ext's is far superior to anyone else's. you can do what you listed in about 20 nicely-formatted lines. i am not kidding.

regarding client-side unit testing, use jasmine with ext.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Frameworks like Ext.js take care of a whole lot code that you would end up writing yourself if you were to write everything from scratch. These frameworks take care of models, events, views, communication with servers/APIs, etc.

Comment: but, like DA said, it really depends on your situation, what sort of application you are making, etc.

Comment: no it doesn't depend. he asked about web apps. dojo and ext are designed for such things. jquery is a nice toy for a web site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answerable question. It all depends.

ExtJS is great for very specific things. If you want those very specific things, it's likely the most efficient option for you.

If jQuery UI meets your needs, then that's your answer.

If you have jQuery dev's, maybe stick with jQuery.

If you have ExtJS folks, consider ExtJS

etc, etc.